# Configuring Custom Save Action Editor WFFM

Tags: wffm

In an installation of Sitecore 7.2 with WFFM 2.4 rev 151103, I am trying to create a new save action that:

1. Send an email with an attachment
2. Uses field conditions so that it is only executed when specific fields are for an example checked.

Looking at what is built-in from start, we have "Send Email" save action that... sends an email, and we have "Send SMS" that allows field conditions to determine whether it is executed.

So basically I've set out to inherit (or duplicate) the functionality from Send Email, and make my additions with file attachments etc. The problem I have is that I can't understand how to wire up my new Save Action Editor.

Reading the documentation for this: https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/create_an_action_editor

The third step just says "...specify the editor that you have created." but doesn't at all explain how that is done. Send Email Message have `control:SendMail.Editor` and I cannot understand how that is wired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the a reference to Sheer UI control in the editor field of the action. Remember, in order to refer to a control in Sheer UI we reference the name of the child element of the root control element inside the XML layout file.
Please see below blog its not based on latest sitecore version but it will be helpful for you.

https://adeneys.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/custom-wfm-action-settings-ui/

Thanks
Mahendra

Comment: I would like to add that that blogpost really didn't explain how your new xml-file was discovered by sitecore. But I ended up putting my new xml-file in `sitecore\shell\Applications\Modules\Web Forms For Marketers\Dialogs\Action Editor` Just putting it in a custom folder didn't work for me, but I might have had some other issue at that time...

thanks!